Characterization of sine and cosine functions. Uniqueness of $\pi$.
I would like to prove the following theorem:
There only exists two functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the following properties:

For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f^2(x)+g^2(x)=1$.
For all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(x+y)=f(x)\cdot g(y)+g(x)\cdot f(y)$.
For all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $g(x+y)=g(x)\cdot g(y)-f(x)\cdot f(y)$.
There exists $\gamma>0$ such that $0<f(x)<x<\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, for all $x\in(0,\gamma)$.

The proof goes as follows:
Suppose that f and g exist and verify the properties the theorem mentions. If we got explicit formulas for those functions which verify the properties of the theorem, we proved the existence and uniqueness at the same time.
We are going to prove a sequence of properties that those function would verify:

For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $-1\leq f(x),g(x)\leq 1$.
$f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=1$.
$f$ is odd and $g$ is even.
For all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)\pm f(y)=2\cdot f(\dfrac{x\pm y}{2})\cdot g(\dfrac{x\mp y}{2})$.
$f$ is continuous.
For all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $g(x)+g(y)=2\cdot g(\dfrac{x+y}{2})\cdot g(\dfrac{x-y}{2})$.
For all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $g(x)-g(y)=-2\cdot f(\dfrac{x+y}{2})\cdot f(\dfrac{x-y}{2})$.
$g$ is continuous.

This is the property where I got stuck.

There exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=0$. Furthermore, $x$ does not depend on $(f,g)$, i.e., if $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are functions verifying the conditions of the theorem and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is such that $g_1(x)=0$, then $g_2(x)=0$. We will define $\pi:=2\cdot\min\{x>0:g(x)=0\}$.

You define $\beta:=\inf\{g(x):x>0\}$. If $\beta>0$ you get a contradiction with $f$ not being upper bounded. Using continuity, you prove the existence of $x=x(g)$. How can I prove the independe of $x$ on $g$?
Proved what's above, it is very easy to see that $f$ and $g$ are uniquely defined for $x=\dfrac{m\cdot\pi}{2^n}$ with $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. The set $\{\dfrac{m\cdot\pi}{2^n}:m,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is dense on $\mathbb{R}$ and, therefore, the extension to $\mathbb{R}$ is unique.
Then we should verify that the properties of the theorem are satisfied with these definitions of $f$ and $g$ to prove existence.
Is there anyone who can help?
Thanks in advance.

Did you prove 1. -8.? And what does "Furthermore, $x$ does not depend on $g$ mean? How can a zero of $g$ be independent of $g$? Or does it mean that one gets the same $x$ for all $(f,g)$ satisfying the four conditions?

Yes, 1-8 is proved. By "$x$ does not depend on $g$" I meant that if $f,g_1,g_2:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are functions that the pairs $(f,g_1)$ and $(f,g_2)$ verify the properties of the theorem and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is such that $g_1(x)=0$, then $g_2(x)=0$.

Sorry, a correction. If $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are functions such that the pairs $(f_1,g_1)$ and $(f_2,g_2)$ verify the properties of the theorem and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is such that $g_1(x)=0$, then $g_2(x)=0$.

You should include this essential information to your question. Comments are not the right place.

These are not Elementary functions,lookup transcendental functions

They are literally the sine and cosine functions. By definition of elementary functions, they are elementary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function. Please, if anyone is going to comment this post, provide some ideas to the problem

"If we got explicit formulas for those functions which verify the properties of the theorem, we proved the existence and uniqueness at the same time." No. That only proves existence. It does not imply uniqueness at all. If you can derive the explicit formulas from the properties, that would imply uniqueness. But just having fromulas that satisfy the conditions does not.

Can you please write down the formulae for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ with $x = \frac{m\pi}{n}$?

Let us call a pair of functions $(f, g)$ an s-c-pair if it satisfies properties 1. - 4.
You have shown that each s-c-pair satisfies facts 1. - 8. We shall moreover prove
Lemma. Let $(f, g)$ be an s-c-pair. Then $f, g$ are differentiable with $f' = g$ and $g' = -f$.
Proof. By 4. we have $1 < \dfrac{x}{f(x)} < \dfrac{1}{g(x)}$ for all sufficiently small $x >0 $. Since $g$ is continuous and $g(0) =1$, we see that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \dfrac{x}{f(x)} = 1$ and thus also $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \dfrac{f(x)}{x} = 1$ (right-sided limits). Since $f$ is odd, we see that also the left-sided limit $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \dfrac{f(x)}{x} = 1$. This means that $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x)}{x} = 1$.
We have
$$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{2f(\frac h 2)g(x + \frac h 2)}{h} = \frac{f(\frac h 2)}{\frac h 2}g(x + \frac h 2)$$
which gives
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = g(x) .$$
The proof of $g' = -f$ is similar.
Let us recapitulate that $\pi = \pi(g)$ was defined as $2\min\{ x > 0 \mid g(x) = 0 \}$. This means $g(\frac{\pi(g)}{2}) = 0$ and $0 < g(t) \le 1$ for $0 \le t < \frac{\pi(g)}{2}$. Hence $f'(t) > 0$ for $0 \le t < \frac{\pi(g)}{2}$ so that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\frac{\pi(g)}{2})$.
By 1. we know that $f(\frac{\pi(g)}{2}) = \pm 1$ and by continuity of $f$ we must have $f(\frac{\pi(g)}{2}) = 1$.
Let us now call a pair of functions $(f, g)$ a nice pair if

it satisfies facts 1. - 8.
there exists a minimal $\pi(g) > 0$ such that  $g(\frac{\pi(g)}{2}) = 0$
$f(\frac{\pi(g)}{2}) = 1$.

Each s-c-pair pair is nice pair.
For nice pairs the functions $f, g$ are uniquely determined by the number $\pi(g)$. In fact, given $\pi(g)$, for $x = \dfrac{m\pi(g) }{2^n}$ the value $g(x)$ can be computed recursively via facts 1. - 8. by starting with $g(\frac{\pi(g)}{2}) = 0$, similarly $f(x)$ can be computed recursively by starting with $f(\frac{\pi(g)}{2}) = 1$. Continuity and a density argument prove then that $f, g$ are uniquely determined by $\pi(g)$.
Let us now consider two s-c-pairs $(f_1,g_1)$ and $(f_2,g_2)$ with $\pi_i = \pi(g_i)$.
Let $a = \frac{\pi_1}{\pi_2}$ and define $f(x) = f_1(ax), g(x) = g_1(ax)$. It is easy to check that $(f, g)$ is a nice pair with $\pi(g) = \pi_2$. Via uniqueness we conclude $f = f_2, g = g_2$.
We have
$$g_2(x) = f'_2(x) = f'(x) = af'_1(ax) = ag_1(ax) = ag(x)  = ag_2(x). $$
For $x = 0$ we get $1 = a$, i.e $\pi_1 = \pi_2$.
